# python remote database connect to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, ssh, sqlalchemy, mysql-workbench

I have a Mac computer and want to connect to a mysql db of an Amazon Linux server.

In terminal I did:

```
sudo ssh -v -i "key_file.pem" -L 22:localhost:22 ubuntu@public.ip.compute.amazonaws.com
```

After that I could connect to the db on Amazon from Mac in MySQL Workbench with following settings:
[image]

However, when I try something like: "mysql -h localhost  —-protocol=TCP -u root -p" or when I try in SQLalchemy:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:password_mysql_amazon@localhost/db?host=localhost?port=3306")
```

I get an error: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

So I switched localhost for 127.0.0.1:22 but then I couldn't find where to add my key_file.pem?

So how do I arrange connection in SQLalchemy to this server that needs to be accessed with a key-file via ssh? Or am going about this all wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with the help of this tutorial (not easy to find): https://medium.com/@amirziai/query-your-database-over-an-ssh-tunnel-with-pandas-603ce49b35a1.

Since I used SQLalchemy I didn't do instructions for pandas + MySQLdb / mysqlclient, but:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (host, 22),
        ssh_username=ssh_username,
        ssh_private_key=ssh_private_key,
        remote_bind_address=(localhost, 3306))

server.start()
engine = create_engine(
        'mysql+mysqldb://root:db_pass@127.0.0.1:%s/db' % server.local_bind_port)`
```